# Node.js json2csv Options Flatten Syntax

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Using the npm json2csv [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) as my guide, specifically this section:

[image]

I am trying to instantiate with transform options to flatten both arrays and objects, but I can't figure out the correct syntax. What I currently have:

```
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');
const json2csvParser = new Parser({ transforms: [flatten({ objects: true, arrays: true })] });
```

which results in:

```
"errorMessage": "flatten is not defined"
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. I am going to leave this here in case anyone else comes across it. This is what worked for me:

```
const { Parser, transforms: { flatten } } = require('json2csv');
const json2csvParser = new Parser({ transforms: [ flatten({objects: 'true', arrays: 'true'}) ] });
```

Apparently the parameters `'true'` needed to be passed in as strings ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Comment: what about if I want to add options like delimiter? thank you